# JFormattedTextField wrong caret position when i type the first number

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, caret, jformattedtextfield

I have modified `NumberFormatter` to have like a currency instance (with prefix).
When I write the first number, this application have add the prefix to the number
[JFormattedTextField Empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPp0X.png)
but when I do that, the caret position change before the first number like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znFCU.png)

How can I fix this by only modifying method `formato()` – that returns a `NumberFormatter` – to the constructor of `JFormattedTextField`?

```java
textFieldMonto = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(formato());
```

This is the method:

```java
private NumberFormatter formato() {
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("'Gs. '###,##0;'Gs. '###,##0");

    NumberFormatter numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(myFormatter) {

        // this change caret to the end in every focus gained
        @Override
        public void install(JFormattedTextField pField) {
            super.install(pField);
            pField.setCaretPosition(pField.getDocument().getLength());
        }

        // allow empty text on JFormattedTextField and dont allow negative numbers
        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
            String result = super.valueToString(value);
            if(super.valueToString(value).startsWith("-"))
                result = result.replaceFirst("-", "");  // this block every negative number
            if(value==null)
                return "";
            return result;
        }

        // allow empty text on JFormattedTextField and dont allow negative numbers
        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
            if (text.length() == 0 || text.equals("Gs. ")) // if is empty or only have the prefix, return null
                return null;
            text.replaceFirst("-", ""); // this block every negative number
            if(!text.startsWith("Gs. "))   //if is empty, add the prefix "Gs. " to the number
                text = "Gs. " + text;
            return super.stringToValue(text);
        }
    };
    numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(false); //this is the key!!
    numberFormatter.setMaximum(new BigDecimal("999999999999"));// maximum number to put
    numberFormatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);// commit value on each keystroke instead of focus lost
    return numberFormatter;
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this comment, in the code in your question, is true:

> `// this change caret to the end in every focus gained`

Method `install` is not called every time the `JFormattedTextField` gains focus. According to my tests, it is called only when a `JFormattedTextField` object is created.

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/InternationalFormatter.html#install(javax.swing.JFormattedTextField)):

> Subclasses will typically only need to override this if they wish to install additional listeners on the `JFormattedTextField`.

Hence I suggest adding a [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to the `JFormattedTextField`'s document, in method `install`.

Note that there are other `DocumentListener`s that are set up by the *Swing* infrastructure and since there is no guarantee regarding the order of execution when there is more than one `DocumentListener`, the implementation, in the below code, uses [invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) to ensure that the listener that I added is run last.

Here is my rewrite of your `formato` method.
The only thing I changed was method `install`.

```
private NumberFormatter formato() {
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("'Gs. '###,##0;'Gs. '###,##0");

    NumberFormatter numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(myFormatter) {

        // this change caret to the end in every focus gained
        @Override
        public void install(JFormattedTextField pField) {
            super.install(pField);
            pField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> pField.setCaretPosition(pField.getDocument().getLength()));
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> pField.setCaretPosition(pField.getDocument().getLength()));
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    // Do nothing.
                }
            });
        }

        // allow empty text on JFormattedTextField and don't allow negative numbers
        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
            String result = super.valueToString(value);
            if(super.valueToString(value).startsWith("-"))
                result = result.replaceFirst("-", "");  // this block every negative number
            if(value==null)
                return "";
            return result;
        }

        // allow empty text on JFormattedTextField and don't allow negative numbers
        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
            if (text.length() == 0 || text.equals("Gs. ")) // if is empty or only have the prefix, return null
                return null;
            text.replaceFirst("-", ""); // this block every negative number
            if(!text.startsWith("Gs. "))   //if is empty, add the prefix "Gs. " to the number
                text = "Gs. " + text;
            return super.stringToValue(text);
        }
    };
    numberFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(false); //this is the key!!
    numberFormatter.setMaximum(new BigDecimal("999999999999"));// maximum number to put
    numberFormatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);// commit value on each keystroke instead of focus lost
    return numberFormatter;
}
```